# Trying to deserialize JSON returns null values

Tags: c#, json, json.net, deserialization, json-deserialization

Using the method JsonConvert.DeserializeObject returns the default values for all properties.

```cs
var current = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Current>(myJson);
```

```json
{
    "location": {
        "name": "London"
    },
    "current": {
        "temp_c": 5.0,
        "cloud": 50
    }
}
```

```
public class Current
{
    public double Temp_c { get; set; }
    public double Cloud { get; set; }
}
```

The expected current object should have the values: 50 for `Cloud`, and 5.0 for `Temp_c`, but returns the default values for all properties.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to define a class model like json object
and then deserialize to it

```
public class YourModel {

   //create location class that has Name property
   public Location Location { get; set; }

   //create current class that has Temp_c and Cloud property
   public Current Current { get; set; }

}
```

and then

```
var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<YourModel>(myJson);
```

and get the current value from data object

```
var current = data.Current;
```

Answer (score 1):

your 'Current' class is far of been like the JSON you post.

You need to convert the JSON string to a C# class. You can use [QuickType](https://app.quicktype.io/) to convert it (Newtonsoft compatible).

Note: I am using System.Text.Json.Serialization but the class model should be equal, just change:

```
[JsonPropertyName("temp_c")] // .Net serializer (I prefer this)
```

to

```
[JsonProperty("temp_c")] // Newtonsoft.Json serializer
```

(replace "temp_c" for every name)

Here is the class model (a complete console application) you need:

```
using System;
using System.Text.Json;
using System.Text.Json.Serialization;

#nullable disable

namespace test
{
    public class Weather
    {
        [JsonPropertyName("location")]
        public Location Location { get; set; }

        [JsonPropertyName("current")]
        public Current Current { get; set; }
    }

    public class Location
    {
        [JsonPropertyName("name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    public class Current
    {
        [JsonPropertyName("temp_c")]
        public double TempC { get; set; }

        [JsonPropertyName("cloud")]
        public int Cloud { get; set; }
    }


    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string json = "{\"location\": { \"name\": \"London\" }, \"current\": { \"temp_c\": 5.0, \"cloud\": 50 }}";
            Weather myWeather = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Weather>(json);

            Console.WriteLine("Location: {0} - Temp: {1:F}", myWeather.Location.Name, myWeather.Current.TempC);
        }
    }
}
```

Now the Deserializer will work OK.